# What is the generic term for Allegri's Miserere-like music?

Tags: history, styles

What is the word/adjective that could describe music pieces similar to [Allegri's *"Miserere"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s45XOnYOIw) or [Henry Ley's *"A Prayer of King Henry VI"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIDFVjXnqc0)?

This music appears to be be sung a capella, with a four-voice choir. (The word I am looking for would be a substitute for *gregorian* in the sentence: *"I really like [gregorian] music!"*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In describing the epoch, you would speak of *Renaissance* music. Describing the form you would speak of a *motet*, which implies music sung a capella or just with instruments doubling the human voices.

Comment: I think that *motet* is the noun I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*Renaissance polyphony* is a term often used for this, which neatly encompasses both the period and the form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of the terms *church music* or *religious music*, since *mass* seems too specific. No term restricting this to  *a cappella* comes to mind and since your examples span some centuries, an epoch-denoting term like *Gregorian* is not appropriate.

Comment: BTW the term is "a cappella" with two p's. (Even though there's only one in "chapel".)

Comment: @RosieF: Thank you for the hint, which I considered; in German the Italian term is valid with an explanation like "also, at least historic: capella".